# Is it possible to order jquery datatable by grouped column headers. If so, where to begin?

Tags: datatables

class='sorting'I have a table that I added an additional row within the  tag to which I am using to indicate grouping of the  columns below it.

I would like to add sorting by the grouping row (top row) so for example when "Group 1" is clicked it sorts the table by the columns under that group (e.g. col1, col2 then by col3).

I am not even sure if this is possible naively in datatables. I would prefer to avoid a jquery hack. My searches have only produced results on row grouping.

datatables version: 1.10.0-beta.1

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mrgulick/usfo2gys/4/

```
<div id="demo">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" class="display" id="example">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th colspan="3" style="background-color:green;border:solid thin;"  class='sorting'>Group 1</th>
        <th colspan="3" style="background-color:blue;border:solid thin;"  class='sorting'>Group 2</th>
        <th colspan="2" style="background-color:red;border:solid thin;"  class='sorting'>Group 3</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th style="background-color:gray;border:solid thin;">ungrouped</th>
        <th style="background-color:green;border:solid thin;">col 1</th>
        <th style="background-color:green;border:solid thin;">col 2</th>
        <th style="background-color:green;border:solid thin;">col 3</th>
        <th style="background-color:blue;border:solid thin;">col 4 </th>
        <th style="background-color:blue;border:solid thin;">col 5</th>
        <th style="background-color:blue;border:solid thin;">col 6</th>
        <th style="background-color:red;border:solid thin;">col 7</th>
        <th style="background-color:red;border:solid thin;">col 8</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>string value 1</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
          <input type="checkbox" checked />
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
          <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
          <input type="checkbox" checked />
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
          <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
          <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
          <input type="checkbox" checked />
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
          <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
          <input type="checkbox" checked />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>string value 2</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
          <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
          <input type="checkbox" checked />
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
          <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
          <input type="checkbox" checked />
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
          <input type="checkbox" checked />
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
          <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
          <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
          <input type="checkbox" checked />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>string value 2</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
          <input type="checkbox" checked/>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
          <input type="checkbox"  />
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
          <input type="checkbox" checked/>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
          <input type="checkbox"  />
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
          <input type="checkbox"  checked/>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
          <input type="checkbox" checked/>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
          <input type="checkbox" checked/>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
          <input type="checkbox"  />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

js below

```
var dt = $('#example').DataTable(dtOptions);

var dtOptions = {
  "dom": '<"clearfix"><"pull-left"l><"pull-right"Bf>r<"horizontal-scroll"t><"pull-left"i><"pull-right"p><"clearfix">',
  "order": [],
  "columnDefs": [{
    "targets": [0],
    "visible": true,
    "searchable": true
  }],
  "aoColumns": [
    null, {
      "orderSequence": ["desc", "asc"]
    }, {
      "orderSequence": ["desc", "asc"]
    }, {
      "orderSequence": ["desc", "asc"]
    }, {
      "orderSequence": ["desc", "asc"]
    }, {
      "orderSequence": ["desc", "asc"]
    }, {
      "orderSequence": ["desc", "asc"]
    }, {
      "orderSequence": ["desc", "asc"]
    }, {
      "orderSequence": ["desc", "asc"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, it's very possible. I don't have time to create a demo at the moment :( https://datatables.net/reference/option/order

Comment: I had reviewed that reference section and ordering related to multi-columns, but it was not helpful to me.

Comment: Here's a quick demo: https://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/usfo2gys/5/. There are many improvements to be made, but it shows the idea.